Alternating Current versus Direct Current
I was given an $I$ v/s $t$ graph that looks like this:

Will it be classified as AC or DC?  The current switches directions once, so not DC (current flow should be in one direction only). I don't think it should be called AC either as it doesn't switch directions at regular intervals, i.e., not $alternating$.

Yes, an AC current would change with time i.e., it is a function of time which reverses its direction periodically whereas a DC source has a steady current. So, the above-mentioned graph is definitely not DC but Iam not sure if that is a AC or not as an AC sign changes periodically.

Does it fit with your known definitions of AC and/or DC?

@MariusLadegårdMeyer No, I have mentioned my known definitions in the question.

DC current can also change with time.  DC current charging a capacitor is changing with time.  You are confusing time dependence with direction of current, they are not the same thing.


Will it be classified as AC or DC?

The behavior of the circuit over the time interval given is neither, though the graph suggests it is the behavior of a circuit connected to a dc source, as discussed below.
A dc source is one in which the current or voltage is constant. An ac source is one in which the current or voltage is changing in time in some periodic fashion, typically (but not necessarily) a sinusoidal wave.
That said, in a circuit there may be a switch or switches that connect or disconnect the dc or ac voltage or current source to/from the circuit. Immediately following the switching action there is a period time when the voltages or currents in the circuit are changing in time, but not necessarily in a periodic fashion. This is primarily due to the presence of capacitance or inductance in the circuit. These currents or voltages are referred to as transients.
Your graph is an example of transient behavior, in this case current. Transients by definition are neither constant nor periodic. So the transient behavior itself is neither ac nor dc, even though the voltage or current source in the circuit may be ac or dc. In time, transients die out and the behavior of the circuit will become either ac or dc depending on the source.
In your case, since the current is approaching a constant positive value over time it suggests the source is dc. Usually in ac circuits, the transient behavior is superimposed on periodic behavior, such as a damped sinusoid. The high initial negative current suggests closing a switch between a voltage source and an uncharged capacitor with very low resistance between the source and capacitor. Eventually it tapers off to some constant value, as shown in your graph to the right.
Hope this helps.

I would agree that the graph there does not show what I would call AC nor DC.  We typically only use those labels for the very obviously sinusoidal signals or the very obvious constant signals.  Also, usually we are referring to the voltages, not the currents.
That being said, you may want to check with whomever gave you the graph to make sure you understand what you were supposed to conclude.  That graph does have the vague shape of what happens when you apply DC voltage to a capacitor.  If they were asking about what sort of input and system could yield such a current curve over time, a DC input could indeed make that happen.  However, without an associated circuit diagram, one cannot be 100% sure.  I can invent a contorted active circuit which yields that current curve for an AC input.  But DC charging a capacitor is much simpler.

I would not call that AC or DC.  AC is periodic, with some frequency (e.g 50 or 60 Hz for most electrical service).  In addition to AC and DC, there is also transient, but that typically implies current or voltage approaching a steady state.  An example would be closing a switch that allows a capacitor to charge or an inductor to conduct.
What you show doesn't fit any of those three.  I doubt that there is a more specific term than just "time varying".
